# Error while connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server database. I am using C#. Here is my code:

```
string connectionString = @"Server = tcp:<myLocalIP>, 1433; Initial catalog = <DatabaseName>;
        User Id = <User>; Password = <Passwd>;",
            queryString = "SELECT * FROM [...]";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        connection.Open();

        myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

        List<String> lst = new List<String>();
        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            lst .Add(myreader[0].ToString());

        }
        connection.Close();
```

But `connection.Open()` throws an error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0).

My server is started, it allows remote connections and TCP/IP is enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your machine's firewall configuration? Also, why use TCP for a local connection?

Comment: I have just checked my firewall and created an exception. The connection is still not established. And I use TCP for local, because I want my app to work over WAN in the future.

Comment: Are you using SQL Express? If so, try Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;

Comment: I got a lot of time this message please check your internet connectivity and then try again it will work.  Basically its an error on connection class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I created a server(Console Application) that connects to MySQL server. Then I connected my Xamarin/ASP.NET application to that server where I process queries.

Answer (score 0):

DBMSSOCN=TCP/IP is how to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes.

Try to change :

```
string connectionString = @"Server = tcp:<myLocalIP>, 1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial catalog = <DatabaseName>;
        User Id = <User>; Password = <Passwd>;"
```

If it won't work, try to hard core IP as in below example :

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword";
```

For more informations: [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Hope that will solve problem, cheers

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. "Network Library" is not supported on ASP.NET and Xamarin.